# Overriding django admin get_queryset method

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following django model:

```
class HeartbeatCell(Model):

    area_id = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=model.DELETE)
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField()
    exit_time = models.DateTimeField()
    cell_id = models.IntegerField()
```

And I want to have an admin page but want to prevent django from loading the whole table when the user first goes into this admin page, as this table is quite big. Thus I am overriding the 'get_queryset' method in the admin model class where I want to limit the columns 'entry_time' and 'exit_time' to an interval equivalent to [now - X seconds, now] in case the user is not making a search which includes any condition on the mentioned columns.

I am using [DjangoQLSearchMixin](https://github.com/ivelum/djangoql) which allows the following searches in any model field: =, >, >=, <, <=, in. These are translated in django fashion to GET url parameters: =, __gt, __gte, ...

I had the idea that request.GET yields a dictionary as along the lines of: "{'entry_time__gte':'2020-01-16 00:00', 'cell_id':52}"  and thus I tried the following:

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
    """Overrides default queryset."""

        qs = super(HeartbeatCellAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)


        for param,value in request.GET.items():
            if 'entry_time' in param:
                return qs

        return qs.filter(entry_time__gte=pendulum.now('UTC') - timedelta(
            seconds= 300))
```

The above code does not work, i.e, the results of the search are not correct, and I ve tried a couple more options but all unsuccessfully. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: "Does not work" is rather useless as a problem description, and "I am trying to see if a query has been made using a given parameter" is a bit unclear - you're talking about the query (I assume "SQL query"), but your code searches `request.GET`, which is the parsed version of the HTTP query string (which by itself has nothing to do with a SQL query). Since you didn't post a proper [mcve] and not even the rest of the ModelAdmin code, we have no reason to know why you would expect the presence of a 'entry_time" arg in the querystring to automagically be turned into a `Queryset.filter()` argument

Comment: Totally unrelated, but the efficient way to test if a dict-like object contains a given key is quite simply `if key in dictlike:` - no need to iterate over the whole set of key:values pairs and test the key.

Comment: Hi bruno, my apologies for the bad problem description. I tried to update it a bit more. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

That `else` block is useless. Change your code to this:

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
    """Overrides default queryset."""

    qs = super(HeartbeatCellAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)


    for param,value in request.GET.items():
        if 'entry_time' in param:
            return qs

    return qs.filter(entry_time__gte=pendulum.now('UTC') - timedelta(
        seconds=HeartbeatCellAdmin.default_secs_past))
```